# How can I detect the autorun process with powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm going to check the PC using powershell.
The purpose is to detect automatic execution malware.
If there is a new process after execution, it shows a new process. Then, I want to create a code that allows users to identify and detect whether it is a malicious process.

```
Function Reg {
$key_1 = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"
$key_2 = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce"
$key_3 = "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"
$key_4 = "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce"

$p1 = Get-Item -Path $key_1 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Property
$p2 = Get-Item -Path $key_2 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Property
$p3 = Get-Item -Path $key_3 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Property
$p4 = Get-Item -Path $key_4 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Property

$result = $p1 + $p2 + $p3 + $p4
$result
}

Function Check {
$file = "C:\study\project\PC_Check\result.txt"
if ( -not (Test-Path $file)) {
    Reg | Out-File -FilePath "C:\study\project\PC_Check\result.txt"
}
else {
    if ((Reg) -eq (Get-Content $file)) {
        Write-Host "No new process."
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "New process detected."
        Reg | Out-File -FilePath "C:\study\project\PC_Check\result.txt"
    }
  }
}

Check
```

The problem with my code is that there is no comparison between the executed output and the contents of the first file.
I want to print out a new process while comparing the current outputs and file contents.

```
(Reg) -eq (Get-Content $file)
```

I think this compare part is wrong, how should I correct it?

Thank you for your time to read this and Have a nice day!

Comment: So, this is your homework assignment...  ;-} Firstly, if you find stuff in those spaces, then that is script kiddies' work, not serious nefarious stuff. There are far more stealthy ways to whack your systems. No serious nefarious threat agent would leave such an easily discovered/visible footprint. Also, why are you not using the defined PS verb-noun construct? Lastly, the comparison is not automatic. You have to code for that. You have other logic issues as well for this to work as you ask. You are not comparing anything in this code. So, step back and step-thru this one step and a time.

Comment: Con't: This is also why the Compare-Object cmdlet exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment. One way to refactor this is as follows. Tweak as needed.

```
Clear-Host

# Refactor to get all Autorun details
Function Get-AutorunDetail 
{
    'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run',
    'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce',
    'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run',
    'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce' | 
    ForEach-Object {(Get-Item -Path $PSitem).Property}
}

Get-AutorunDetail | 
Out-Null

Function Write-AutorunResultsFile
{
    # Check if file path exists
    $AutorunResultsFile = 'D:\study\project\PC_Check'

    # If not, create the path and the new file
    if ( -not (Test-Path -Path "$AutorunResultsFile\AutorunResultsFile.txt")) 
    {
        New-Item -Path $AutorunResultsFile -ItemType File -Name 'AutorunResultsFile.txt' -Force | 
        Out-Null

        # Add the Autorun detail to the new file
        Get-AutorunDetail | 
        ForEach-Object {Add-Content -Path "$AutorunResultsFile\AutorunResultsFile.txt" -Value $PSitem}
    }
    else 
    {
        if (Compare-Object -ReferenceObject {Get-AutorunDetail} -DifferenceObject (Get-Content -Path "$AutorunResultsFile\AutorunResultsFile.txt"))
        {Add-Content -Path "$AutorunResultsFile\AutorunResultsFile.txt" -Value 'No new process.'}
        else 
        {
            'New process detected.'
            Get-AutorunDetail | 
            ForEach-Object {Add-Content -Path "$AutorunResultsFile\AutorunResultsFile.txt" -Value $PSitem}
        }
    }
}

Write-AutorunResultsFile
```

Again, this is just one way, there are always more and/or better ways - but I'll leave them to you to research or others to chime in.

***Updated***

```
Clear-Host

# Refactor to get all Autorun details
Function Get-AutorunDetail 
{
    'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run',
    'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce',
    'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run',
    'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce' | 
    ForEach-Object {(Get-Item -Path $PSitem).Property}
}

Get-AutorunDetail | 
Out-Null

Function Write-AutorunResultsFile
{
    # Check if file path exists
    $AutorunResultsFile = 'D:\study\project\PC_Check'

    # If not, create the path and the new file
    if ( -not (Test-Path -Path "$AutorunResultsFile\AutorunResultsFile.txt")) 
    {
        New-Item -Path $AutorunResultsFile -ItemType File -Name 'AutorunResultsFile.txt' -Force | 
        Out-Null

        # Add the Autorun detail to the new file
        Get-AutorunDetail | 
        ForEach-Object {Add-Content -Path "$AutorunResultsFile\AutorunResultsFile.txt" -Value $PSitem}
    }
    else 
    {
        if ($AutorunDetails = (Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-AutorunDetail) -DifferenceObject (Get-Content -Path "$AutorunResultsFile\AutorunResultsFile.txt")) -match '<=')
        {
            Add-Content -Path "$AutorunResultsFile\AutorunResultsFile.txt" -Value 'New process detected.'
            Add-Content -Path "$AutorunResultsFile\AutorunResultsFile.txt" -Value ($AutorunDetails.InputObject | Select-Object -Last 1)
        }
        else 
        {Add-Content -Path "$AutorunResultsFile\AutorunResultsFile.txt" -Value 'No new process detected.'}
    }
}

Write-AutorunResultsFile

# Results when altering the registry key
<#
Security...
Tablet...
Display...
ms...
OneDrive
Micros...
CiscoM...
...
Docker Desktop
GoToMeeting
No new process detected.
New process detected.
test
No new process detected.
New process detected.
test1
No new process detected.
New process detected.
test2
#>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :)
But the same problem happened.
The results are printed on the text file without any problems at the first run.
If I add the string value 'test' to regedit and run it again, the 'New process detected' phrase is not printed, and the 'No new process.' phrase is printed.
Is there anything I did wrong or missed?

Comment: That is because you have to tell your script to do this, as I've shown in the 'No new process', line. See my update for you. You have to really do more than what you have shown to deal with the potential overall use case. What you are after is not difficult, it's just a matter of taking things one step at a time, and making sure you are getting what you'd expect before taking the next step.

Comment: Thank you so much!
Your answer makes me understand the powershell I am doing for the first time.
Have a nice day today.